# offset_column in h2o.gbm

Tags: r, h2o, gbm

I'm using H2O 3.10.4.1

I'm trying to fit a Bernoulli model with GBM using some initial predictions from some other model and I'm getting worse Likelihoods than starting predictions. I was able to reproduce it using titanic data.

I was able to use R's gbm to do what I want. R's gbm.fit asks for offset on the link scale, which is not restricted, it could be very high or very low negative values.

However, when I try to do the same in H2O GBM, it throws an error:

> water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument(s) for GBM model: GBM_model_R_1489164084643_3568.  Details: ERRR on field: _offset_column: Offset cannot be larger than 1 for Bernoulli distribution.

My Jupyter notebook is here:
[Github](https://github.com/Denisevi4/test/blob/master/Test_Titanic.ipynb)

**UPDATE**
I was able to use offset, but only for a dataframe where ProbabilityLink is less than 1. Since H2O complains about it. See cells 65-68 in the Notebook.

I believe that this is a bug in H2O. They should just remove the requirement that offset must me less than 1 for Bernoulli. It can be anything. And then it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

**updated**

for older versions of H2O (3.10.2 or less) you have to use a value less than 1 for a Bernoulli distribution with H2O gbm's `offset_column`. **However**, for newer versions you will be able to pass in any value. In your case, using a Bernoulli distribution, one way to create the offset column is to use the predicted logit values from a previous model (just as you said you wanted to do in the comments).

This is how the gbm offset column works:
An offset is a per-row “bias value” that is used during model training. For Gaussian distributions, offsets can be seen as simple corrections to the response (y) column. Instead of learning to predict the response (y-row), the model learns to predict the (row) offset of the response column. For other distributions, the offset corrections are applied in the linearized space before applying the inverse link function to get the actual response values. This option is not applicable for multinomial distributions.

And here is a example of how to use this parameter on a toy dataset

(example with Bernoulli distribution)

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# import the cars dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify whether or not a car is economical based on
# the car's displacement, power, weight, and acceleration, and the year it was made
cars <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
cars["economy_20mpg"] <- as.factor(cars["economy_20mpg"])

# create a new offset column by taking the log of the response column
cars["offset"] <- as.h2o(rep(.5, dim(cars)[1]))

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors <- c("displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year")
response <- "economy_20mpg"

# split into train and validation sets
cars.split <- h2o.splitFrame(data = cars,ratios = 0.8, seed = 1234)
train <- cars.split[[1]]
valid <- cars.split[[2]]

# try using the `off_set` parameter:
# training_frame and validation_frame
cars_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, offset_column = "offset",
                  validation_frame = valid, seed = 1234)

# print the auc for your model
print(h2o.auc(cars_gbm, valid = TRUE))
```

Gaussian example (where it makes more sense to use this option)

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# import the boston dataset:
# this dataset looks at features of the boston suburbs and predicts         median housing prices
# the original dataset can be found at     https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing
boston <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/gbm_test/BostonHousing.csv")

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors <- colnames(boston)[1:13]
# set the response column to "medv", the median value of owner-occupied     homes in $1000's
response <- "medv"

# convert the chas column to a factor (chas = Charles River dummy     variable (= 1 if tract bounds river; 0 otherwise))
boston["chas"] <- as.factor(boston["chas"])

# create a new offset column by taking the log of the response column
boston["offset"] <- log(boston["medv"])

# split into train and validation sets
boston.splits <- h2o.splitFrame(data =  boston, ratios = .8, seed = 1234)
train <- boston.splits[[1]]
valid <- boston.splits[[2]]

# try using the `offset_column` parameter:
# train your model, where you specify the offset_column
boston_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train,
               validation_frame = valid,
               offset_column = "offset",
               seed = 1234)

# print the mse for validation set
print(h2o.mse(boston_gbm, valid = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi Lauren, could you provide an example with Bernoulli please? That's where my confusion is. Your example is with Gaussian.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model, link function which I need to use to get to the linear space for Bernoulli is logistic ln(mu / (1-mu)), which is what I used for my example.... But H2O complains that the offset has to be less than 1. What did I do wrong? Or more importantly, what H2O is expecting me to do?

Comment: I added this Boston example to my [notebook on GitHub](https://github.com/Denisevi4/test/blob/master/Test_Titanic.ipynb). I adapted it to what I'm trying to do, not just some arbitrary offset, but a prediction from glm. And it works fine. So, I have no problem with Gaussian. But Bernoulli is still a problem

Comment: updated it for you, you just need to provide a offset column that contains values less than 1, hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not helpful at all. In your example you just added some arbitrary offset of 0.5. I don't want an arbitrary offset. I want to use offset that corresponds to the prediction from a glm model. And I want to know how to construct it. I updated the [Github](https://github.com/Denisevi4/test/blob/master/Test_Titanic.ipynb). Look at cells 16, 17 and 18. There I added "something" that is less than 1, right? Namely I added Probability from GLM. However, LogLoss even after the first tree is 0.6. The GLM model has a LogLoss of 0.48. It cannot increase!

Comment: Maybe you can at least answer the question why is that " If the distribution is Bernoulli, the value must be less than one."? I want to know the reasoning.

Comment: I updated my original post. I believe that this is a bug in H2O. They should just remove the requirement that offset must me less than 1 for Bernoulli. It can be anything. And then it should work fine.

Comment: I think all its going to take is remove lines 94-97 from [https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/tree/gbm/GBM.java](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/tree/gbm/GBM.java)

Comment: @Denisevi4 thanks for digging into this, you're right there shouldn't be a limit we updated the current code https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/commit/468ec37ee193f9cf3e880748a11575e478aea416 (you can git pull now or wait for the next release) and will update the docs. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Lauren! I guess I'll be using Nightly Bleeding Edge release for now to take advantage of the fix.